# Disable anti-aliasing by default in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, antialiasing

I'm making a game in cocos2d that uses "old-school" style graphics, and I don't want the sprites to be antialiased in any way. I can use `[[sprite texture] setAliasTexParameters]` to disable the antialiasing, but I need to do that for every sprite, and it clutters the code. Is there any way to do it globally by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit `CCTexture2D` code to `setAliasTexParameters` by default, but that will mean updates to cocos2d will be a headache really fast.
What I done when I needed this, I wrote a function to create the textures for me and it called `setAliasTexParameters` on each.

Comment: I ended up just making a factory method, though it seems a little silly to not be able to easily set this. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

CCTexture2D.m

```
 - (id) initWithData:(const void*)data pixelFormat:(CCTexture2DPixelFormat)pixelFormat pixelsWide:(NSUInteger)width pixelsHigh:(NSUInteger)height contentSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if((self = [super init])) {
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1);
        glGenTextures(1, &name_);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, name_);

        [self setAliasTexParameters];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get the same effect by reducing the pixel format.

[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444];

If not, you could create a factory that sets the setAliasTexParameters as the texture object is instantiated reducing the code clutter.